# Creating different functions on odd click and even click on link

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have 3 links which are the names of students.On clicking a link first time or odd number time,another div which contains the details of that student appears.On clicking the same link on second time or even number time, I need to hide the student div.Its working perfectly for me using `data()` event of jquery.

My requirement is if I click first student link,div with the details of first student will come.If I click the second student link,details of second student will come.If I again click on first link,the student div will hide since `data()` is associated with it(*I think so*). But I want to make it displayed because,previous click was on the second link.

My html is like this

```
<a href="" id="24" class="student_link">George</a>

<a href="" id="25" class="student_link">Leo</a>

<a href="" id="26" class="student_link">Kelm</a>
```

My jquery:

```
$("#sections ").on('click','.student_link',function(){
       var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
      //alert(clicks);
      if (clicks) {
         $("#div_students").hide();
         //alert(1); 
      }
      else
      {
         $("#div_students").show();
         //alert(2);
      }

      $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
      return false;
   });
```

That is if I click George for first time, the corresponding div of student will appear,If I click Leo without clicking George to hide the div,I need div of Leo should come.If I click George again,I need div with details of George should come.But for me the div is hiding since the variable click is already true for George.I need the div to be displayed if previous click was not on the current link.

Comment: Instead of storing a count for number of clicks, it sounds like you would rather hide if shown and show if hidden. Try using that logic instead, as it's more intuitive to what you want to accomplish.

Comment: @MariM But if I use the logic where the div is shown and hidden,I think I cannot do,because if the displayed student is different from the clicked student,I need to display the div

Comment: an easy approach is to hide all student-info on click and show the one requested

Comment: Maybe it's an Accordion you really want: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
$("#sections").on('click', '.student_link', function () {
    var prevClickedId = $('#sections').data('prevId');

    if (prevClickedId != $(this).attr('id')) {
        // This was not the previous clicked element
    } else {
        // This was the previous clicked element
    }

    $('#sections').data('prevId', $(this).attr('id'));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This is not what OP is asking for. OP want to an even number of clicks on a link, not every other link.

Comment: If I clicked  a particular link and then click the second student,so now the second student details is shown.When I click the first student link,I need div it to be displayed,but  acocrding to the code,number is even for that link,so it will hide right...

Comment: @Techy Check updated answer. If not work, please create jsfiddle with all the relevant code

Answer (score 1):

You can so something similar to this:

```
$("#sections").on('click', '.student_link', function(){
    if( $("#div_students").data('viewing') == $(this).attr('id') ) {
        $("#div_students").hide().data('viewing', '');
    }
    else {
        $("#div_students").show().text($(this).attr('id'));
        $("#div_students").data('viewing', $(this).attr('id'));
    }
    return false;
});
```

Here's a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/7qwsguoq/

Comment: Its not working if I click on same link simultaneously,I mean the div is not hiding

Comment: @Techy Is the data set correctly and the if statement working?

Comment: Ya...rest of the things are working,but it is not hiding if I click on same student link after the first click

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just use jquery `toggle()` method? it hides element when it's visible, and shows when it's hidden.

Comment: if div is shown,it will hide if I use toggle().But if the shown div is different of clicked student link,what can I do